# PySide Signals in separate file

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am writing a GUI application using Qt and PySide and I usually connect my signals in the **init** function of my class. How can I put all my signals in a separate file and then call the function from the file in my main file? Something like this.

```
import Signals
class Program(QtGui.QMainWindow, GUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Program, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        Signals.ConnectSignals()
```

Signals.py

```
class ConnectSignals(QtGui.QMainWindow, VUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConnectSignals, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.actionClose.triggered(self.close)
```

But when I do that, I get this message
self.actionClose.triggered(self.close)
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the rest of this should/will work, but the error is because youare missing `.connect`  I think it should be

```
self.actionClose.triggered.connect(self.close)
```

`self.actionClose.triggered` is a signal (as I assume `actionClose` is an action) and the error is telling you that signals do not have `__call__` defined.